# How to Iterate Across Fields as Inputs for a single tool (Kernel Density) in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, kernel-density

I am trying to make Employment Distribution of map of a given area in ArcGIS. All the employment information is in this one point shapefile from Census. Different fields show different number of employment for different industries. 
[image: The Fields]
Now I want to use each field as population field input in Kernel Density tool. There are like 18 fields so I am wondering how I could use iterator or some other way to do it more efficiently.

The model I used is shown as below:

[image: Model]

What shall I do to finish this job?

This was marked as duplicated by Mods, which I understand. But I am just wondering if this could be done merely in ModelBuilder.

Comment: In what way does the marked duplicate not work for you?

Comment: I don't know how to run Kernel Density in Arcpy. I needed a little more detailed instruction. But the problem is solved anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is possible unless you use some coding. Either as a standalone script or imported into Modelbuilder. I Think you should use a standalone script which you can execute in the [Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm):

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *

#Change to match your data:
input_fc=r'C:\TEST.gdb\polygon567'
out_folder=r'C:\TEST'

#List all fields that starts with c. Or you can specify them manually for example ['ce01','ce02']
fieldlist=[f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(input_fc) if f.name.startswith('c')]

#Execute kernel density for each listed field
for field in fieldlist:
    outKernelDensity=KernelDensity(in_features=input_fc, population_field=field)
    outKernelDensity.save(os.path.join(out_folder,'Outraster_{0}.tif'.format(field)))
```

The outputs will for example be named

> Outraster_ce01.tif

Comment: Thank you so much, but I couldn't get it through. The last step is the problem: Output raster: L:...\Distribution Maps\SaveTRY.gdb\Outraster_{0}.tif\cns01's workspace is an invalid output workspace. ERROR 000875. I have tried folder or file geodatabase. It just doesn't work. What shall I do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewLebron : I have changed the last line. I had a comma where there should be a dot (.format)

Comment: Thank you so much sir. That comma took me like 3 hours, but I still couldn't fix it haha. Rudimentary understanding of Arcpy. Couldn't do this without you. THANK YOU SO MUCH sir! BTW I don't know who downvoted you, this is like perfect.

Comment: Hi sir it's me again. Not sure if you can see this still. I've been learning Python a little bit so now I came back to see the Python code that helped me before. I don't quite get the part in your code with for loop and if statement: [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(input_fc) if f.name.startswith('c')] could you share a link where I can read or learn more on this please? Thanks a lot

Comment: Google list comprehension